# Django Celery Multiple shared tasks

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

So I'm trying to use two different shared tasks inside of my django project. Let's call them task1 and task2. Task1 gets called and worked perfectly fine but whenever the code tries running task2 it doesn't work. The task logger doesn't log anything inside of the task2 function and there is no record of it in rabbitmq/celery. I have supervisor handling the celery workers. Can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong so both task1 and task2 get called?

**supervisord.conf**

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/tmp/supervisor.sock                       ; path to your socket file

[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/supervisord/supervisord.log    ; supervisord log file
logfile_maxbytes=50MB                           ; maximum size of logfile     before rotation
logfile_backups=10                              ; number of backed up logfiles
loglevel=info                                  ; info, debug, warn, trace
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid                ; pidfile location
minfds=1024                                     ; number of startup file descriptors
minprocs=200                                    ; number of process descriptors
childlogdir=/var/log/supervisord/               ; where child log files will live

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock         ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket

[include]
files=celeryd.conf
```

**celeryd.conf**

```
; ==================================
;  celery worker supervisor
; ==================================

[program:celery]
; Set full path to celery program if using virtualenv
command=/path/to/celery worker -A proj --loglevel=INFO

directory=/path/to/proj
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery/worker.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery/worker.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10

; Need to wait for currently executing tasks to finish at shutdown.
; Increase this if you have very long running tasks.
stopwaitsecs = 600

; When resorting to send SIGKILL to the program to terminate it
; send SIGKILL to its whole process group instead,
; taking care of its children as well.
killasgroup=true

; if rabbitmq is supervised, set its priority higher
; so it starts first
priority=998
```

**proj/celery.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os

from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')

from django.conf import settings

app = Celery('proj',
     broker='amqp://name:password@localhost:5672/vhost',
     include=['proj.tasks'])

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

**proj/tasks.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from celery import shared_task
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
from django.conf import settings

celery_logger = get_task_logger('celery-task')

@shared_task
def task1(args):
    # Do stuff

@shared_task
def task2(args):
    # Do stuff
```

**proj/util/process.py**

```
from ..tasks import task1, task2

def function(args):
    task1.delay(args)
    if bool:
        task2.delay(args)
```

Comment: `if bool`? Try `if True` and see if it works.

Comment: I have tried that as well. It gets to the task, but still does not run it.

Comment: If you remove the conditional entirly, does task2 run? If not, does swapping the two tasks work? I'm kind of stabbing in the dark because from the code you provided it isn't clear what the issue is.

Comment: So what was happening was task2 wasn't performing it's job. I traced through process.py to make sure the task2.delay function was being hit and it was, but nothing was happening inside the task. I hadn't looked at the code for awhile so I tried again today and task2 is now being hit, however I'm trying to update a model from inside of it but now the model object isn't being updated. I hope that made sense. Thanks for your help btw!

Comment: And now I got it working. I tried testing it outside of our testing env and it worked fine. Went back to the tests and realized I forgot the override_settings decorator. Stupid mistake